# how to localise jcolorchooser

Tags: java

As part of a college project we are localising our application.

Is it possible to localise swing components such as JOptionPane and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ResourceBundle](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for localization in general (in option pane case for the choise strings and messages) . Then you can use those localized Strings etc for the JOptionPane. For example:

```
String[] choises = new String[];
choises[0] = bundle.getString("yes");
choises[1] = bundle.getString("no");
choises[2] = bundle.getString("cancel");

String message = bundle.getString("messageText")

JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(message, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, null, choises);
```

For more details for resource bundles check out [Java Internationalization: Localization with ResourceBundles](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Intl/ResourceBundles/).